# Calculate percentage of same specific values per group

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have the following dataframe df (`dput` below):

```
> df
   group class value
1      A FALSE     2
2      A  TRUE     1
3      A FALSE     1
4      A FALSE     2
5      A FALSE     3
6      B FALSE     4
7      B FALSE     2
8      B  TRUE     2
9      B FALSE     2
10     B FALSE     6
11     C  TRUE     5
12     C FALSE     5
13     C FALSE     3
14     C FALSE     5
15     C FALSE     5
```

I would like to calculate the percentage of specific similar values per group. There is always one value with the `class == TRUE`, which means I would like to calculate the percentage of values similar to the value with `class == TRUE`. As you can see in the dataframe above group A has the value 1 with class == TRUE and there are two values with 1 in group A so 2/5 = 0.4 of the values are 1. Here is the desired output:

```
  group value pct
1     A     1 0.4
2     B     2 0.6
3     C     5 0.8
```

So I was wondering if anyone knows how to calculate the percentage of specific values per group in R?

---

`dput` of df:

```
df <- structure(list(group = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C"), class = c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), value = c(2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 2, 2, 6, 
5, 5, 3, 5, 5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -15L
))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
library(dplyr)#version >= 1.10
df %>%
   reframe(pct = mean(value == value[class]), value = value[class], .by = group)
```

-output

```
   group pct value
1     A 0.4     1
2     B 0.6     2
3     C 0.8     5
```

---

Or with a `data.table` option

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[df[(class)], .(value = i.value,
  pct = mean(value == i.value)), on = .(group), by = .EACHI]
   group value pct
1:     A     1 0.4
2:     B     2 0.6
3:     C     5 0.8
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarize(pct = sum(value == value[class == TRUE])/n(),
            value = value[class == TRUE])

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  group   pct value
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A       0.4     1
2 B       0.6     2
3 C       0.8     5
```

Answer (score 2):

A base R option with `ave` + `subset`

```
subset(
  transform(
    df,
    pct = ave(ave(class, group, value) > 0, group)
  ), 
  class
)
```

gives

```
   group class value pct
2      A  TRUE     1 0.4
8      B  TRUE     2 0.6
11     C  TRUE     5 0.8
```